# Why is my PHP/MYSQL code resulting in an increment of 2 as opposed to 1?

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm currently designing a website as kind of a demo/project. I'm doing computer sciences in college and this includes some web design. I'm looking to go in to web design in the future, and just felt like designing a website with a bunch of different functions just to scratch up on my knowledge and have something to show potential employers.

I'm currently learning PHP, so my issue is probably being caused by something glaringly obvious... I just can't see it.

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, name, description, views FROM videos ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql); 

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $viewIncrement = "UPDATE videos SET views = views + 1 WHERE ID=" . $row["ID"] . " LIMIT 1";
        if ($conn->query($viewIncrement) === TRUE) { echo " Success."; } else { echo " Failure: " . $conn->error . "."; }
    }
}
```

So, here's the basic code.

It's part of a larger system, where I echo some HTML to display the video that is selected (the most recent addition), and then add 1 to the 'views' row. It works fine, except it increments 'views' by two, rather than one.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try limiting the UPDATE command like: UPDATE videos SET views = views + 1 WHERE ID= $row["ID"] LIMIT 1 ?

Comment: First change: `$result = $conn->query($sql) or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());` --> `$result = $conn->query($sql);` use just one API suggested mysqli

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What if you try setting the value in PHP not SQL:
`$viewIncrement = "UPDATE videos SET views = " . intval($row["views"]) + 1 . " WHERE ID=" . $row["ID"];`

Comment: Are you sure the script runs only once? What happens when you run the `UPDATE` statement directly in MySQL?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. The problem is outside the code you have posted. How did you confirm that the script is executed only once?

Comment: In order to check the real value `echo $row["views"]` before the update query... and you can check how many times is send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you posted, it looks like the query is getting executed twice.

One thing to check -- do you by any chance have a broken  tag on the page you're loading to run this script?

This:

```
<img src="/bad/image/path" />
```

Will actually cause some browsers to load the page a second time. I've personally experienced this.

I don't know if other broken resources (such as bad  or css imports) will also cause this.

Comment: Turns out my server is completely case sensitive, which was resulting in a small overlay not loading, and, as you said, this made the browser reload the page. That's definitely not something I would have ever thought of.

Comment: Yep. Hours upon hours upon hours of debugging helped me discover this about 3 years ago. Glad the information could be of use!